# Does Kylo Ren want to be a sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, sith, darth-vader, kylo-ren

Kylo Ren clearly has an obsession with emulating Darth Vader. He also wants to "finish what [Darth Vader] started".

Darth Vader was a sith, so then wouldn't Kylo Ren wish to become one? To complete Vader's mission, wouldn't Kylo Ren have to adopt Vader's fundamental sith principles? With the sith being defeated, Kylo Ren doesn't really have the resources for an authentic sith training.

Has he settled with being a dark side user lead by Snoke, or does he want to become a sith, as was Vader?

Comment: When he grows up, do you mean?

Comment: Just as one of his ambitions. Wouldn't he have to become one to finish what Vader started?

Comment: Dear Santa, I want a new bike, a lightsaber that doesn't vent and a [how-to-book on how to be a sith](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1452118159/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1944687722&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=1452126410&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=11Z9DHZTY76KWVXT1N6C).

Comment: @Richard I'm pretty sure Ren is going to get coal...

Comment: @JoshB. - he already got ashes in a tasteful ashtray, [to place he helmet in](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113246/what-does-kylo-ren-place-his-helmet-on/113247#113247)

Comment: If he wanted to become a Sith, he would worship Palpatine aka Darth Sidious, not Darth Vader, who was never the mastermind of the Sith (and, in a way, "failed" to excel at Sith-ness). It's clear Kylo Ren feels a connection *specifically* to Vader, so the Sith thing must be a red herring.

Comment: This question, and possible answers, are probably going to come down to interpretation - mostly because of the ambiguity inherent in "finish what [Darth Vader] started".

What is it that Ren thinks Vader started? And what does Ren think he needs to do to finish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't know, as of the current canon.

The only meaningful evidence comes from his enemies, in that, really, whatever-Ren-is, and the Sith, are pretty much the same thing in different brush strokes:

```
MAZ
The only fight: against the dark side. 
Through the ages, I've seen evil take many forms. 
The Sith. The Empire. Today, it is the First Order. 
Their shadow is spreading across the galaxy. We must face  them. Fight them. All of us.
```

(*WGA script*)

Neither J.J. Abrams, or Visual Dictionary, nor novelization, offer any meaningful details on what distinguishes these guys from Sith except for their abilities (see below), other than confirming that they aren't Sith.

---

Having said that, I **really** don't see why he'd want to be a Sith **instead** of what he is.

Remember: this is a half-trained acolite (Snoke tells Hux to fetch him from StarKiller after he's injured, because it's time to finish training him):

```
SNOKE
Leave the base at once and come to me with Kylo Ren.
(grim)
It is time to complete his training.
```

And yet he can:

- **Freeze blaster bolts** in mid-air and suspend them there

  > Kylo Ren RAISES HIS HAND -- POE'S BLAST FREEZES -- THE BOLT
  >   OF ENERGY STRAINING AND VIBRATING IN MID AIR!
  >   Kylo Ren sees Poe, who suddenly CANNOT MOVE, but strains to.
  >   He is grabbed by Stormtroopers who drag him past the
  >   VIBRATING, FROZEN BLAST, to Kylo Ren.
- **Freeze humans**

  > She FIRES ferociously, but Kylo Ren keeps coming! His hand
  >   rises -- Rey suddenly STOPS -- GASPS -- UNABLE TO MOVE.

  or see Poe in the quote above
- **Mind-read**

  > KYLO REN (CONT'D)
  >   ... You're so lonely... so afraid to leave...
  >   (then, slight smile)
  >   At night, desperate to sleep... you imagine an ocean. I see it -- I see the island...
  >   Tears stream down her face as she resists. She tries to break free, but can't budge.
  >   KYLO REN (CONT'D)
  >   And Han Solo. You feel like he's the father you never had. He would've
  >   disappointed you

**Neither Vader nor even Sidious could do those things**, so whatever Snoke is training Kylo Ren to be, it appears to be a more powerful and thus appealing shade of the Dark Side.

So far, the only meaningful Force Power we saw the Sith display in canon that Kylo Ren didn't do yet is shooting <strike>bolts of lightning from his arse, [Braveheart-like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcoVxbutl8g)</strike> Force Lightning out of his hands.

Answer (score -4):

From what I've read there are very very very few 100% true native Siths left in the universe. Most have been diluted due to crossbreeding. Thus he can't "become" a Sith anymore than a person born a Hawaiian wants to be German as he was born to Luke & Lea. Obviously he's a fanatical follower of Sith order with exceptional powers so he may be accepted into the "brotherhood" of Sith.

Comment: I think you may be mistaking "Sith" ([race](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_(species))) with "Sith" ([Order of Dark Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith))