# Is Snoke associated with the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, sith, snoke

Are there any existing in/out-of-universe evidence that suggests whether Snoke is a Sith or not?

It seems that it is generally agreed he is not a Sith Lord from the Banite order of the Rule of Two, given that he is believed to be at least a thousand years old. But is it possible he is a Sith Lord **not** from Darth Bane's order?

The Jedi believed the Sith are extinct but they are mistaken. The Sith believed there are only two of them in existence, but that belief originated from Bane - I haven't seen anything that externally supports that belief. That opens the possibility that Snoke could be a fellow Sith Lord who survived the war, escaped the Jedi's notice, and wasn't aware of fellow Sith survivors - and as such he's not compelled to follow the Rule of Two.

In other words, even if Snoke is proven to not be a Banite Sith, he's not necessarily not a Sith from a more ancient era.

Putting aside the above speculations in my head, what in/out-of-universe resources are there that have touched on this topic: whether Snoke is associated with or a member of the Sith Order?

Comment: JJ Abrams has said that he is over 1000 years old so I think that he is a Sith from before the Bane line. My personal Theory is that he is Darth Malgus.

Comment: But I could easily be wrong

Comment: @TheMandalorian Given so much has been relegated to Legends, I refuse to put a name on him since I am more likely wrong than not. I do believe in my headcanon though that he may be Sith after all - and Ben will finish what Anakin started. And who knows: Imagine if his Sith name is Darth Ren!

Comment: @TheMandolorian cant be maglgus. Malgus was missing the lover part of his face completely and had an augment built. Also Malgus was killed off in SWTOR.

Comment: Crap, oh well it was just a hope.

Answer (score 5):

### Signs point to "No".

In an [interview with Empire magazine](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/jj-abrams-spills-details-kylo-ren/), Abrams said,

> "Kylo Ren is not a Sith," confirms JJ Abrams in the new issue of Empire. "He works under Supreme Leader Snoke, who is a powerful figure on the Dark Side of the Force.”

Now, there are a number of articles that are taking this as confirmation that [Snoke is not a Sith](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3719178), which I'm not personally willing to put a stamp on just yet, but it's a reasonable conclusion.

[The Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/supreme-leader-snoke) says this about Snoke:

> The Supreme Leader of the First Order, the mysterious Snoke has no permanent base of operations, preferring to contact his underlings from a mobile command post. Snoke is powerful with the dark side of the Force, and seduced Kylo Ren into abandoning the Jedi path to become his apprentice. But Snoke also commands General Hux and the technological war machine the First Order has engineered to destroy the New Republic and Leia Organa’s Resistance.

We know that Kylo Ren isn't a Sith, and there's not much evidence that [he wants to be one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113354/5184).

So, Ren is not a Sith, but is an apprentice under Snoke, confirmed by StarWars.com, and the movie which mentions Ren's training under Snoke.

---

Kylo Ren is not a Sith, but is being trained by someone with great Dark Side powers, but who is probably not a Sith himself.

Comment: Hmm, being a Sith is just a title tbh. Kylo may see himself, as leader of the Knights of Ren, a successor to the Sith Order. But putting Kylo aside (he's not the subject of the question asked), the evidence here for Snoke not being Sith seems weak. Just because an apprentice isn't recognised as Sith doesn't mean the master isn't. There's a long history of it: Tyranus and Ventress, Vader and the Inquisitorius. Like you, I won't put a stamp on it too, but I'm less inclined to go as far as to say it's probable.

Comment: If it looks like a Sith, quacks like a Sith, takes apprentices like a Sith, and uses the Dark Side like a Sith... it's another nearly-identical organization, with no real significance. It's also a huge letdown, since we have at least four such organizations in Disney Canon, but no alternate Light Side organizations.

Comment: If you disagree with my assessment, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: Touchy, Phantom! We were agreeing with you.

Comment: One point maybe to add there (just found this questions). Lukas himself said the prophecy was fullfilled (and it was to destroy the sith). If snoke is/was a sith then the prophecy was never fullfilled.

Comment: @Slacklord - Which would those be? We have the Sith, the Inquisitorius, and that's all I can think of. Are you counting the Nightsisters?

Answer (score 1):

I think Snoke may have been a Sith but not a Lord as he was bested by Rey and Kylo, like how Darth Sidious was trained to be a Sith Lord but went away from that meerly mis-using the force and through the years doubting its power and mostly using Science and Technology, Snoke too is doing it as well tagging Kylo to believe he is ONE WITH THE FORCE

Comment: Do you have something to support that?

Answer (score -1):

After i heard that Snoke is over 1000 I thought he might be Set Harth (the one who obtain Andeddu holocron after Bane), also I've seen that Snoke isn't a sith, but with another news I've found Snoke is new character.

Comment: Do you have sources to back this up?