# If Snoke was around, there was never any balance of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, anakin-skywalker, snoke

1) George Lucas has said that Anakin brought balance to the force by "doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe". If Snoke, who we can probably assume is skilled in the dark side of the Force, was around at the time of Palpatine's death, doesn't that mean that Anakin/Vader did **not** in fact bring balance to the Force, and was **not** the 'chosen one'?

2) Even if we were to answer that Snoke wasn't yet proficient in the Force at the time of the Emperor's death, how lame is the prophecy looking now - Anakin brought balance for maybe 20 years at most! As Lor San Tekka says in The Force Awakens: "Without the Jedi, there can be no balance in the Force" - clearly whatever balance Anakin achieved has quickly been lost (and even those few years between ROTJ and TFA weren't any better than those of the old Republic!). But from watching the prequels, you'd think the balance of the force would be a big deal, or at the very least last longer than a decade or two?!

Comment: I thought Anakin brought balance to the force by making the Jedi an endangered species much like the Sith, so, balanced.

Comment: @phantom42 not at all; I'm going with what G. Lucas said that Anakin brought balance by destroying the Emperor - that's already an assumption of my question, I'm taking it for granted.

Comment: He brought balance by destroying the Sith (a cult that was intentionally disfiguring the Force for their own twisted ends), not by going around killing every dark side user.

Comment: I feare the problem is until star wars 8  we just dont know enough about snoke to answer this question fully

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124997/is-snoke-associated-with-the-sith?rq=1

Comment: @woody it depends. The main problem is that the balance was said by lukas that it was to destroy the sith (even the jedi thought so). And currently we don't know anything about snoke there. If he is a sith then the prophecy was not fullfilled (speculations about him being darth bane). If he is no sith (JJ said it himself that kylo is no sith and no sith shown in 7) then the prophecy is true.....from a specific point of view at least. Especially as some characters thik only the existence of the jedi can bring the force back into balance (begin of star wars 7).

Comment: @Valorum see the quote from Lor San Tekka I added - clearly there isn't a balance even though there aren't any Sith - so getting rid of the Sith is not enough to achieve balance

Comment: Seems like a bad dupe closing. This question is centered on Snoke, who isn't even mentioned in the other question or accepted answer.

Comment: @DCShannon the closers probably think it's already answered there because it says balance was restored by getting rid of the SITH specifically, and Snoke is not Sith. However, the words of Lor San Tekka would seem to contradict that notion - balance is unrelated to the Sith specifically.

Comment: @Woody Probably. I think it would be a lot better to write an answer to this explicit question, which would probably reference those other answers or the information in them.